# MySQL - easiest way to insert multiple table rows - doing a foreach

Tags: mysql, foreach, insert

Ok i have 2 tables,

```
users_table: id | firstname

messages_table : id | id_to | id_from | message
```

what i'm trying to do now is getting all `users_table` ID and insert for each one id a message in `messages_table` (so send messages to all users using one query)

i'm trying somenthing like this :

```
foreach $users_table.id do:

    INSERT INTO messages_table (id_to,id_from,message) VALUES ($users_table.id, 5, "Hey man!");
```

Can i do that without a server side script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) statement as long as the other parameters are constant (or can be derived from other tables):

```
INSERT INTO `message_table` ( `id_to`, `id_from`, `message`)
SELECT user.`id`, 5, "Hey man!"
  FROM `users_table` user
```

Comment: testing it out it sounds awesome rly awesome thanks, just what if want to exclude some users.id from the SELECT?

Comment: @sbaaaang For testing I suggest just to run the `SELECT` part of the query. If the result fits your needs, than run the complete query. Inside the `SELECT` part you can use a `WHERE` clause like usual.